What did Winston Churchill mean when he said "We didn't come this far because we're made of sugar candy."
I found Winston Churchill made these two " sugar candy" quotes,

"We didn't come this far because we're made of sugar candy."
"We have not journeyed all this way across the centuries, across the oceans, across the mountains, across the prairies, because we are made of sugar candy."

I read the the first one from David McCullough's "The American Spirit: Who We Are and What We Stand For", check the following screenshot, at the chapter "which way forward"

I didn't understand it so I search the quote and found the second quote from National Churchill Museum. But I didn't know enough of the context to get the meaning too.
--- update ---
I further searched the context of the first quote and find this article

After the attack on Pearl Harbor, Winston Churchill said that the
American people–he said, the American people, he said, and this is a
direct quote, “We didn’t come this far because we are made of sugar
candy.”

I can't verify whether the article said was the case. Whether  Winston Churchill said those words after the attack on Pearl Harbor. But I think that is the reason my question is valid here and if folks still down-vote it please at least leave the comment why.

Source for these ‘cites’? Sure doesn’t sound like Churchill.

I suspect the specific "sugar candy" being referenced is what is more commonly, in North America at least, referred to as "candy floss".

@PieterGeerkens "Cotton Candy" is more common in North America.

Candy is an American word. Churchill still used words like 'foe' which his fellow countrymen had stopped using a century before - he is not a good candidate for an early adopter of a word which most British people don't use even decades later.

As a non-native speaker I didn't know whether these quotes were well-known or not (now I see they weren't) so I didn't add their sources at the first. My bad. But I feel you guys jump to the conclusion too quickly (I always feel that is a big problem in SO)

Yep you're right, it is. And you were right that the quote was genuine, so sorry about that. You got a bad reaction partly because the internet is a machine for making up quotes which are utter bollocks - this has been a huge problem for decades and AI has made it so much worse. For this reason it's always a good idea to provide a source from the start, which you've now done. I hope you will stick around - I've always said we need more non-native speakers and a broader range of questions.

Thanks for the comment. After I added the sources I still got down-votes so I was a bit annoyed. For the first "quote", I got a comment saying that it maybe McCullough was paraphrasing Churchill, or just didn't remember the exact phrasing(the second one) I think it maybe a more plausible explanation.

Your second link both provides the historical context and an explanation of the meaning by simply looking at the rest of the speech. This is from a speech given to the Canadian Parliament on dec 30 1941 discussing the demands of WW2 on the British (and Canadian) people:

I should like to point out to you that we have not at any time asked
for any mitigation in the fury or malice of the enemy. The peoples of
the British Empire may love peace. They do not seek the lands or
wealth of any country, but they are a tough and hardy lot. We have not
journeyed all this way across the centuries, across the oceans, across
the mountains, across the prairies, because we are made of sugar
candy.
Look at the Londoners, the Cockneys; look at what they have stood up
to. Grim and gay with their cry "We can take it,"

The phrase in question is an indication of the strength and determination of the people when facing adverse situations such as war. Sugar candy just melts away, as some people might when facing adversity, Churchill was indicating and congratulating the British peoples' strength in facing the war thrust upon them.

Okay I realized this maybe a language issue(I read the paragraph before I asked). He said "we have not ... because we are made of sugar candy.". Did that mean because we are made of sugar candy, we are not tough enough, so we have not accomplished something  or ... ?

No, he is saying that they would not have been able to accomplish those things if they were like sugar candy. Since they did all those things it shows they (the British people) are not 'sugar candy'.

Thanks, so this does sound like a language issue to my understanding. So I can assume the first one "We didn't come this far because we're made of sugar candy." actually means we come this far because we are not made of sugar canay ?

That's correct.

Hi please check my update. I seem to find the context of the first quote but I can't verify that.

@Qiulang邱朗 - For me the defining quality of sugar candy is that it melts away to nothing in the rain (or in your mouth, or really any time exposed to a bit of moisture). Other candies and sweets do this too of course, but the effect is particularly pronounced with sweets made entirely from flavored sugar. Perhaps it is a cultural thing, if you didn't have parents who told you "You won't melt in the rain!" Its kind of a metaphor for not being afraid of dealing with a little adversity.

Well, a culture thing that stroke me a long time ago was when PM of UK apologized to Turning, "So on behalf of the British government, and all those who live freely thanks to Alan's work I am very proud to say: we're sorry, you deserved so much better." You are proud to say you are sorry, what kind of logic is that?! Shouldn't he say "we are so shameful to say we are sorry?! That was a long time ago and your words brought that back again.

"Sugar candy" is not a phrase one would associate with Churchill (as other comments have noted; it's certainly not current English and it's unlikely it was then). Was his speech tailored for a Canadian/North American audience?
